# frontpage blog layout with random ordering in joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

one of my clients (www.expertmanage.com) requires random ordering of frontpage articles. We are using Joomla 1.5. I have gone through primary order and category order options, but there is no way to show up articles in random order. Can this be achieved somehow by editing the query on front page blog layout controller ?

Answer (score 0):

If you goto Joomla's extension website, you can find some that can help you. Try auto-frontpage for instance ([here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/10986)) or you can search the list of frontpage extentions. I'm sure you would find a solution to your problem ([frontpage extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news))